# Merging several xlsx files into one

Tags: python, pandas

In a directory, I have several xlsx files, and I would like to put them in one single xlsx file. So I did this code:

```
all_data=pd.DataFrame()
for item_excell in arr2:
    if item_excell.endswith('.xlsx'):
        df=pd.read_excel(item_excell)
        all_data=all_data.append(df, ignore_index=True)

 all_data.to_excel('final_table.xlsx')
```

My previous excell have header, and I would like to keep them, because with this code, I don't get the header and the information gets mixed up.

Comment: all_data.to_excel should be outside of the "for".

Comment: is your python version greater than 3.4?

Comment: Yes, Im using python 3.7.2

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

For example, If you have 3 `.xlsx`  files:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('file 1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('file 2.xlsx')
df3 = pd.read_excel('file 3.xlsx')

final_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
final_df.to_excel('combined file.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

as others have noticed your `all_data` should be outside your for loop,

as taga has provided an answer, i'll show you how using `Pathlib` which was added into Python in version 3.4 and allows for really high level interactions with your file-system with minimal code.

```
from pathlib import Path
your_dir = r'c:\path\to\excels' #r for windows.
```

now we make use of `glob` which allows for wild-card matching to find all the excels in a given location using list comprehension

```
excels = [f for f in Path.(your_dir).glob('*.xlsx')]
```

this is the same as

```
excels = []
for file in Path.(your_dir).glob('*.xlsx'):
    excels.append(file)
```

now you can concat your dfs

```
dfs = [pd.read_excel(frame) for frame in excels)]
final_df = pd.concat(dfs)
# do stuff
final_df.to_excel('file_name.xlsx',index=False)
```

Comment: this way I only get one xlsx file.But it's odd because when I print final df, I get all tge files. But when it writes, It only shows the last entry

Comment: maybe you need to specify your sheet names as your excels may have multiple sheets so you're returning an ordered dict, try `[pd.read_excel(frame,sheet_name='YOURSHEET') for frame in excels)]` and change yoursheet to the sheet you need to concat